# A data structure to keep the smallest values on line

Tags: algorithm

Let say, we have a string of characters (say their values are in the rang of `0--255` for **ASCII** and the range of `0--65,535`).

**Here is the list of tasks may be applied:**

1. keep tracking the indices of each unique character (latest one);
2. get the character with the smallest `index`;
3. update the data structure (remove the one returned in 2 and add a new one).

Here is an example, and the index **i** goes from **0 to 17**

```
aabbaaaacccddccccc
```

we may track the string online like this, where the integer inside the parentheses is the index of the corresponding character:

- a(0)
- a(1) b(2)
- a(1) b(3)
- ...
- a(7) b(3)
- a(7) b(3) c(8)
- ...
- a(7) b(3) c(10)
  Now we read the character 'd' and we need to update the data structure with the rule, say, remove the element with the smallest index: b(3) and add d(11)
- a(7) d(11) c(10)
- ...

We may use a hashmap to track the indices of each unique character:

```
Map<Character, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>(m);
myMap.put(new Character(input.charAt(j)), j);
```

But when we want to get the character with the smallest index, we may go through the map one-by-one, which is not as efficient as what I wanted.

We may use priority Queue to store the elements,which did give me O(1) time to fetch the smallest element; but I cannot update the priority queue the same as the map.

Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as your map myMap from character to position, you could also update a SortedMap from position to character.

For each character c input you would:

1. Look up c in myMap to find its index i
2. If it is present, then remove key i from the SortedMap
3. Change myMap[c] to point to the new index
4. Change SortedMap[new index] to point to c

When you want to find the element with the smallest index, you can simply look at the first element of the SortedMap.  With a SortedMap this is an efficient operation.

Comment: One more TreeMap did solved the problem:
Map<Character, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>(m);
TreeMap<Integer, Character> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>();

All pairs (Key, value) are added into myMap above and 
all pairs (value, key) are added into sortedMap above.

Thanks.